# DatagridVIew single cell formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, cell-formatting

Tried to found aswer on this question, but didn't found anything working for me.
I need to change font color (bacground color etc.) of a single cell in my dataGridView based on different conditions.Fof example - value in another cell from the same row in this dataGridView.
All solution that i found previously doesn't solve this problem for me.

Below is my suggestion for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:
You need to create event datagridView_cell_Formating:

[image: dataGridView CellFormating]

And add a code similar to this:

```
 private void datagridView_cell_Formating(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Target_column")
        {
            if ((e.Value != null) && (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Condition_cell"].Value.ToString() == "value"))
            {
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if ((e.Value != null))
            {
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Every DataGridView has a `DefaultCellStyle`. Every `DataGridViewColumn` of thie DataGridView may have a `DefaultCellStyle`. If this is NULL, then the `DefaultCellStyle` of the DataGridView is used. To see the actual cell style used by the column, use `InheritedCellStyle`

Similarly, every DataGridViewCell has a `Style`. if it is null, it uses the `InheritedCellStyle` of the column of the cell, so if this column has a null `DefaultCellStyle,` the `DefaultCellStyle` of the `DataGridView` is used. The actual used Style of the DataGridViewCell is in property `InheritedCellStyle`.

- Cell has a non-null Style: InheritedStyle equals this
- Cell has null style, column has non-null Defaultstyle: Cell.InheritedStyle equals Column DefaultStyle
- Cell has null style, column has null DefaultStyle: Cell.InheritedStyle equals DataGridview Style

If you only want to change the cell style of a certain cell X, just set the DefaultCellStyle. You can take a Clone of the InheritedStyle and change the properties.

```
void SetCellBackColor(DataGridViewCell cell, Color color)
{
    cell.Style = (DataGridViewCellStyle)(cell.InheritedStyle.Clone());

    // or slightly more efficient:
    if (cell.Style == null)
       cell.Style = (DataGridViewCellStyle)(cell.InheritedStyle.Clone());

    cell.Style.BackColor = color;
}
void SetCellBackColorToDefault(DataGridViewCell cell)
{
    // set Style to null; the Column's InheritedStyle will be used
    cell.Style = null;
}
```

Comment: Do some debugging and write some test code. What does your debugger say about the cell's InheritedStyle.BackColor? Does it equal the cell's Style.BackColor? What does HasStyle say? Make some test code in which the DataGridview / Column / Cell each have different back colours, so you can see which BackColor is it showing: the one of the DataGridView, the one of the Column, or the one of the Cell?

Comment: So the code indeed changes the inherited style. What is the color of the inherited style: is it the color of the Cell Style you just set, or is it the color of the column, or the gridview. By the way: you do know that things like GdiCharSet and vertical fornt etc are not important in this discussione, kindly remove them from the comments. Or even better: edit your original question, so you can do some proper formatting. Now I can hardly read it. Dit you read MSDN about styles and inherited styles?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't read it yet, but it'll be the next thing i'll learn.
I think it should be usefull for those who search for solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
       protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        string temp = dr[3].ToString().Trim();
        int sub = int.Parse(temp);

           foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
               if (sub > 0)
               {
                e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.Coral;
                }
                if (sub > 25)
                 {
                  e.Row.Cells[5].BackColor = Color.Coral;
                 }
               }
           }
      }
```

if this doesn't help please elaborate more on the requirement.